# PHPExcel filling 0 values in range formulas

Tags: phpexcel

Using PHPExcel 1.7.9, I am reading an Excel template and filling values in specific cells only before sending the file to the user.

The template is full of range formulas which calculate totals on columns and rows. Trouble is, no matter what, the formula value is always set to 0 with the Writer instead of remaining blank (which is the actual Excel behaviour).

I tried using the `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);` method, to no avail.

It would certainly be possible to rewrite all the formulas and apply conditions to circumvent the issue but it's not ideal, and looking quite overkill.

Just for the sake of information, here is my Writer code:

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($obj);
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($obj)->clearCalculationCache();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Depends what the formula is: not all formuals will give a result of 0

Comment: Of course. They are all `SUM`s.

Comment: Odd, because if I do SUM() on an empty range of cells in MS Excel itself, I get a 0 value result rather than a blank... and I'd expect a 0 value. What version of Excel are you using that gives a blank?

Comment: It's always behaved that way, in all versions of Excel (we've been using this template for years now, so from Excel 2003 to Excel 2010 today). I tried to look into the formula properties but with no real success.

Comment: Then I'm uncertain what the situation is: the version of MS Excel I'm using at this moment (2013) gives a zero.... I'll need to wait till tonight to go back through previous versions to check; but I think it's highly unlikely that I can simply find a "fix" that will display a blank when there are no numeric values to sum rather than a 0, especially as it will fail a lot of tests as a result

Comment: Mark, thanks for redirecting me to Excel. I thought it was an issue in the PHPExcel code, but it seems to stem from the template I am using. No need to check on previous versions: running a `SUM` on an empty cell range in 2010 gives 0 as a result indeed. I just cannot figure out how this is possible. Will post the result when (if?) I do.

Comment: Ah, of course... In Excel 2010 that is just a matter of checking/unchecking "Show a zero in cells that have zero value" in the Excel Options > Advanced > Display options for worksheet. Now my trick question is: since the Reader/Writer is resetting this at some point, can PHPExcel ultimately handle that option?

Answer (score 1):

I used `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);` and the zeroes disappeared.